Laravel 11 with MongoDb get error "Call to a member function prepare() on null"
In laravel 11 I  get the error while login. Now the error occured on createToken method.
Controller
  public function login($request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $member = Member::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if (!$member || !Hash::check($request->password, $member['password'])) {
            return response()->ErrorResponse('Email or password is incorrect.');
        }
        Auth::login($member);
        $token = $member->createToken('Personal Access Token')->plainTextToken;
        return response()->SuccessResponse($member);
   }

The code works till the line Auth::login($member). When I call the CreateToken the error occurs.
Model/Member.php
 namespace App\Models;

 use MongoDB\Laravel\Eloquent\Model;
 use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
 use MongoDB\Laravel\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

 class Member extends Authenticatable
 {
  use HasApiTokens;

  protected $connection = 'mongodb';
  protected $collection = 'Members';

  protected $fillable = [
    'userName', 'email', 'status', 'createdDate', 'password'
  ];

  protected $casts = [
    'createdDate' => 'datetime',
    
  ];

}

config/auth.php
  'guards' => [

     'api' => [
        'driver' => 'mongodb',
        'provider' => 'members',
        'hash' => false,
     ],
  ],
 
   'providers' => [
    'members' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Member::class,
    ],
  ],


Connectivity with MongoDB is not properly setup since SQL connection would expect a prepare() method that MongoDB doesn’t use.Are you sure that you have properly installed and configured the MongoDB driver in the application ?

Yes.. mongodb installed and configured properly.. Found the issue using sanctum package which is designed for SQL databases and relies on SQL-specific methods.

Yes that is correct but still you can use Sanctum with MongoDB check this links.

https://github.com/mongodb/laravel-mongodb/discussions/2242


@Subha Fixed the issue. Thankyou for your response.

To use Laravel Sanctum with Laravel MongoDB, modify the PersonalAccessToken model provided by Sanctum to use the DocumentModel trait from the MongoDB\Laravel\Eloquent namespace.
Created Model Models/PersonalAccessToken.php
namespace App\Models;

use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken as SanctumToken;
use MongoDB\Laravel\Eloquent\DocumentModel;


class PersonalAccessToken extends SanctumToken
{
  use DocumentModel;
  protected $connection = 'mongodb';
  protected $collection = 'personal_access_tokens';
  protected $primaryKey = '_id';
  protected $keyType = 'string';

}

Reference : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/php/laravel-mongodb/v4.6/user-authentication/#std-label-laravel-user-auth-sanctum
